# xcode app cannot download at this time

Tags: xcode

I have developed an IOS app for distribution as an enterprise app (in house).
I ahve exported the app from xcode creating a .ipa and manifest.plist file.

Testing out the install from my server via the internet the app asks "Do you want to install", click yes and after a short time I get the message "app could noy be downloaded at this time"

If however I connect my iPad to my Mac and run xcode the app is installed without any issues.

Versions:
xCode 7.2

I have checked the "manifest.plist" file and all the information looks correct.

Does anyone have any ideas at what I should look at?

I have my iPad connected to my Mac, xCode Devices window open. When I try to install the app from my web server this is the resulting log output:

```
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 itunesstored[123] <Warning>:     LaunchServices: installing placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy:   0x14c785c40> com.mydomain.PK <(null) *Not found in database*>
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5497886380363912570.app" type Placeholder (LSInstallType = 1) requested by itunesstored (pid 123)
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.mydomain.PK; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.mydomain.PK at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/76FEFBD9-65CA-47F3-B47A-1D54721B5D41
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.mydomain.PK at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88A708CB-F525-4A5C-BE5C-FA8D30CB5EB1
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.01s; Overall: 0.08s
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 itunesstored[123] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14c6e77d0> com.mydomain.PK (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88A708CB-F525-4A5C-BE5C-FA8D30CB5EB1/5497886380363912570.app> withPhase:3
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 itunesstored[123] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.mydomain.PK.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x14c7e36a0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 itunesstored[123] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x14da22000> com.mydomain.PK (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88A708CB-F525-4A5C-BE5C-FA8D30CB5EB1/5497886380363912570.app> with icons
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5497886380363912570.app" type Placeholder (LSInstallType = 1) requested by itunesstored (pid 123)
 Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e2d3000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.mydomain.PK; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e2d3000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.mydomain.PK is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C3A1550-1613-488D-B388-DAF4245BC94D
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e2d3000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.mydomain.PK at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BB9DDBFB-EE87-440E-B866-08FB0E29D064
Feb 23 09:39:11 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e2d3000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.02s; Overall: 0.24s
Feb 23 09:39:12 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 nsurlsessiond[114] <Error>: Task 11 for client <CFString 0x19a7bff20 [0x19eebcb68]>{contents = "com.apple.itunesstored"} completed with error - code: -999
Feb 23 09:39:12 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 itunesstored[123] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14d84a8a0> com.mydomain.PK (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BB9DDBFB-EE87-440E-B866-08FB0E29D064/5497886380363912570.app> withPhase:0
Feb 23 09:39:12 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 itunesstored[123] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.mydomain.PK.Loading - <NSProgress: 0x14db28770> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1 of 1   called, removing progress from cache
Feb 23 09:39:12 PKLHR-Syndicate-99 lsd[164] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x15655f420> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
```

and then the install hangs with the message "Unable to Download App" "Con1" could not be downloaded at this time. The app icon on the iPad says "Waiting".

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. After many hours of testing I found that in my ViewController there was a missing "[super viewDidLoad];. The strange thing is that the code complied and run in a simulator, ran when I connected my iPad directly to my Mac via USB.

At no time did xcode provide or display any errors or warnings. I should have noticed the missing line of code at the start of my problem.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Is the site you are downloading it from https? You will get that error if its only http.

Check that the ipa file is actually addressable by the device by putting the full path to it in Safari - that wont install it, its just a check that the file is available where you think it is.

The other possibility is that the device is not in your provisioning profile. You need to add the device's UDID to the appropriate provisioning profile and the clean and rebuild your application. To do that have a look at this document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

at the "Registering Individual Devices" section and make sure you device is registered there - if not, add it.

You then need to go into XCode and  in the Preferences menu select Accounts then your Apple ID and View Details. Hit the refresh icon and then re-export and deploy your application to your website. It should hopefully download fine.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have been trying all day to get this working with no result. The site has a https cert. As far as I can see the provisioning profiles are correct. If there is an issue with the provisioning profile would it still install when the iPad is connected to my Mac and perform a run from within xCode. Because the app is going to be installed on a number of devices  why would adding the UDID to the profile help. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: I had a very similar problem over the weekend - I was installing my application on my iPhone via XCode and USB cable and everything was fine. It also installed fine OTA to the same iPhone but on a different device I got the same error that you did. Adding that second device's UDID to the provisioning profile, rebuilding and redeploying the ipa worked to fix that. I also had a typo in my page href, which should look something like this: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://myWebsite/myApp/myApp.plist (I was wrongly just doing a simple http link to the plist file

Comment: Are you exporting for "Ad-hoc' deployment or just Developer? I used Ad-hoc myself

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have included a copy of the log output when running this with my iPad attached to my Mac.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am exporting for "in-house Enterprise"

Comment: I've updated the answer - i think if you have the icon at waiting state its down to the provisioning profile. I would add the device explicitly to the provisioning profile. I'm not sure if the provisioning profile for development and enterprise are separate (not at my Mac just now) but i suspect that might be the case and if so add it to the enterprise provisioning profile. I hope that works...